# How to get Attributes from annonymus delegate

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a custom attribute from a delegate that uses parameters.

```
[SomeCustomAttribute]
private void MyFunction(int i){ ... }

void Function(Action method){
        foreach (var attribute in method.Method.GetCustomAttributes(false))
        {
            if (attribute is SomeCustomAttribute)
            { ... }
        }
}
```

this works fine as long as i dont use parameters in the delegate like:

```
() => MyFunction(1);
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing `() => MyFunction(1);` to the `Function` method, as in

```
Function(() => MyFunction(1));
```

You naturally won't get any attributes, as `() => MyFunction(1);` is a lambda function and as such doesn't have attributes.

I assume `MyFunction` does have attribute(s). So, in order to get them, you'll need to change (or create an overload) the signature of the `Function` method to

```
void Function(Action<int> method) {
...
```

so that you could pass it `MyFunction`

```
Function(MyFunction);
```

Comment: Or he could simply `Function(delegate method)`

Comment: Not really, @xanatos